# Raspberry PI camera stream, ethernet communication

Tags: sockets, raspberry-pi, stream, ethernet, picamera

I am trying to use Rpi PI 4 for video stream. I used some example from web attached below. This program create server from Rpi and when i write IP of Rpi to my browser and have Rpi and PC on the same network i can se realtime stream from this camera. Then i want to send some data via ethernet from PC to rpi for example some commands for servo which will control the camera rotation. I have two program which work properly.But when i want to run this application as one program (Thread for stream and for message recceiver from PC) i always got error adress already in use. That seems logic. Is there some suitable option how to do what i want or i must choose different way of solution?

**Camera stream on Rpi**

```
import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server

PAGE="""\
<html>
<head>
<title>Raspberry Pi - Surveillance Camera</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Raspberry Pi - Surveillance Camera</h1></center>
<center><img src="stream.mjpg" width="640" height="480"></center>
</body>
</html>
"""

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
            # clients it's available
            self.buffer.truncate()
            with self.condition:
                self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
                self.condition.notify_all()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
        return self.buffer.write(buf)

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='640x480', framerate=24) as camera:
    output = StreamingOutput()
    #Uncomment the next line to change your Pi's Camera rotation (in degrees)
    #camera.rotation = 90
    camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
    try:
        address = ('', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        camera.stop_recording()
```

**PC send msg to Rpi**

```
import socket
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('192.168.1.145',8000)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)

while 1:
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        message = connection.recv(1024)
        message = message.decode('utf-8')
        print(f'Accepted msg from pc {client_address}: {message}')
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Comment: use a different port number for one of them?

Comment: I tried this before. It works, but only when i run two programs separately with python idle. But when i write one program with 2 Threads it didn't work because i got error OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use.

Comment: ... use a different port number for one of them?